# Simple convert rows to columns in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have structured database which connected to SCADA platform and look something like that:

"Stations" table:

| StationID | StationName | PumpNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A01 | 2 |
| 2 | B01 | 4 |
| 3 | C01 | 1 |

"PumpsRH" table:

| Date | PumpNo | RunningHours | StationID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-10 | 1 | 12 | 1 |
| 2023-06-10 | 2 | 14 | 1 |
| 2023-06-10 | 1 | 15 | 2 |
| 2023-06-10 | 2 | 10 | 2 |
| 2023-06-10 | 3 | 20 | 2 |
| 2023-06-10 | 4 | 15 | 2 |
| 2023-06-10 | 1 | 20 | 3 |
| 2023-06-11 | 1 | 11 | 1 |

I need the result to be for each station separately  :

| Date | Pump 1 | Pump 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-10 | 12 | 14 |
| 2023-06-11 | 11 | etc. |

| Date | Pump 1 | Pump 2 | Pump 3 | Pump 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-10 | 15 | 10 | 20 | 15 |

etc.

Keep in mind that is a simple example. The actual DB is more complex and this data will join other tables.

I found online solution which uses dynamic query like that:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName) 
                    from yourtable
                    group by ColumnName, id
                    order by id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                select value, ColumnName
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for ColumnName in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

But I am not expert and couldn't apply that solution on my case. Also I don't know if the SCADA will have the permission to execute dynamic queries.

Comment: _"Keep in mind that is a simple example. The actual DB is more complex and this data will join other tables."_ - we can't help you unless you show us your **actual** schema and sample data (feel free to obfuscate as necessary). Asking us to play with an oversimplified version of your schema won't help anyone.

Comment: The fact that you want to do this in a dynamic method really suggests that this should be a task in your presentation layer, not the SQL layer. Tables aren't spreadsheets, sp transposing data (dynamically) isn't as simple as copy, paste transposed, far from it.

Comment: This is a classic pivot, and there are tons of previous examples. If you have a known number of pumps you can skip the dynamic thing and just hardcode select max(case when pump = 1 then RunningHours END) as pump1... The actual aggregation code is more complex and this code will need to be copypasted with slight changes, but you should be able to figure it out

Comment: Just extending some other comments.... _why_ do you want to pivot? If it's for a report, then use the report to do the pivoting. If it's to load data into another database, keep in mind that you will likely need to unpivot again at some point

Comment: This screams of being an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version of the pivoting because, as Dai answered in a comment above, you didn't provide the actual schema. In any case, the idea of dynamic rotation should be clear.

```sql
declare @StationID int = 1,
        @cols nvarchar(max),
        @query nvarchar(max)

set @cols = stuff(isnull((select distinct ', [Pump '+ cast(PumpNo as nvarchar) +']'
                                                from PumpsRH where StationID = @StationID 
                                                for xml path('')),''),1,2,'');

/*
--Another variant how to retrieve @cols using string_agg() function
set @cols = (select string_agg('[Pump '+cast(PumpNo as nvarchar)+']', ',') 
             from (select distinct PumpNo from PumpsRH 
                   where StationID = @StationID) tmp
            )
*/

set @query = N'select [Date], ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
              select [Date], RunningHours, ''Pump '' +cast(PumpNo as varchar)+'''' as PumpNo
              from PumpsRH where StationID = '+cast(@StationID as nvarchar)
             +N') x
             pivot 
             (
                sum(RunningHours)
                for PumpNo in (' + @cols + N')
             ) p ';

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

[image]